# Push/pull door latch

Tags: doors

I have a massive front door and it has large beautiful handle rods on it. When it comes to choosing a lock set, I want the top bore to use a deadbolt for when the door needs locked. But for the bottom bore, I don’t want a lever or knob that must be operated to release the latch. I want to be able to push the door closed and this would activate the latch. And I want to be able to pull the handle and the motion of pulling the door open would release the latch. What would this mechanism be called?

Comment: It sounds like you want something like a spring door roller latch, or a self closing door spring/cylinder.

Comment: I take it this front door leads to the outside, and that there are no hurricane/windstorm requirements in your area?

Comment: There are push/pull paddles manufactured for use with commercial doors. Whether you would like the look of them, I can't tell you; I wouldn't like them on a residence unless there was an accessibility issue they solved. A local locksmith can tell you more about what currently exists, whether any of it would work without retrofitting your door with a mortise mechanism, and what prices would be. I haven't had reason to look at this in the past decade at least, so all I can say is that it isn't impossible but may be impractical.

Comment: @keshlam I put one of these in my garage door (didn't match *exactly* the other rotate-only handles in the house, but close enough, and doesn't look like the commercial type): https://buyhampton.com/collections/brinksppr-levers/products/brinksppr-glenshaw-ppr-door-lever  Game changer when coming into the house with full hands.  (Still doesn't solve the OP's issue.)